# Using genio with array

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

Hi I'm trying to get a program to work that will ask the user to input Arrays using bluej, for this I was planning on using Genio but when I type the code below I get the following message:

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]

```
public class Arrays
{
    public int[] numbers;

    public void testIntegerArray()
    {
        numbers = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers = Genio.getInteger();
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Genio.getInteger();` // returns an integer

Your are assigning an integer to an array which you can't.
To add the integer to your array you need:

```
numbers[i] = Genio.getInteger(); //your forgot the [i]
```